# Trying to put a chartjs chart on top of an image

Tags: javascript, chart.js

As stated in the subject, I have a chart.js chart that I'm trying to render on top of an image but it just doesn't seem to be working.  Either no image at all shows up, or it shows up somewhere else.  No javascript errors that I'm seeing either.  I'm seeing a lot of people using .png files for this, but I'm using .jpg files, hopefully that's not the issue.  Been trying to use pointStyle and have that point to an img tag id defined in the html.

Below is the code thanks in advance!

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Gauge Chart</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.js"></script>
    <script>
    Chart.defaults.gauge = Chart.defaults.doughnut;

var gauge = Chart.controllers.doughnut.extend({
    draw: function(ease) {
        //Chart.controllers.doughnut.prototype.draw.call(this, ease);
        var meta = this.getMeta();
        var pt0 = meta.data[0];

        var ctx = this.chart.chart.ctx;
        ctx.save();

        var cx = pt0._view.x;
        var cy = pt0._view.y;
        var innerRadius = pt0._view.innerRadius;
        var outerRadius = pt0._view.outerRadius;
        var config = this.chart.chart.config;
        var current = config.data.current;
        var max = config.options.panel.max;
        var min = config.options.panel.min;
        var needle = config.options.needle;
        var panel = config.options.panel;
        if (current >= max) {
            current = max;
        }
        if (current <= min) {
            current = min;
        }
        var needleAngle = config.options.circumference * (current - min) / (max - min) + config.options.rotation;
        var radius = outerRadius * needle.lengthRadius / 100;
        var textRadius = outerRadius * panel.scaleTextRadius / 100;
        
        ctx.translate(cx, cy);
        ctx.font = "" + panel.scaleTextSize + "px, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif";
        ctx.fillStyle = panel.scaleTextColor || 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)';
        panel.scales.forEach(function(value, index, arr) {
            var textWidth = ctx.measureText("" + value).width;
            var textAngle = config.options.circumference * index / (arr.length - 1) + config.options.rotation;
            var dy = textRadius * Math.sin(textAngle);
            var dx = textRadius * Math.cos(textAngle);
            ctx.fillText("" + value, dx - (textWidth / 2), dy);
            var oy = (outerRadius * panel.scaleOuterRadius / 100) * Math.sin(textAngle);
            var ox = (outerRadius * panel.scaleOuterRadius / 100) * Math.cos(textAngle);
            var iy = (outerRadius * panel.scaleInnerRadius / 100) * Math.sin(textAngle);
            var ix = (outerRadius * panel.scaleInnerRadius / 100) * Math.cos(textAngle);
            ctx.strokeStyle = panel.scaleColor || 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)';
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(ix, iy);
            ctx.lineTo(ox, oy);
            ctx.stroke();
        });
        ctx.restore();

        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(cx, cy);
        ctx.strokeStyle = panel.tickColor || 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)';
        ctx.beginPath();
        this.chart.chart.config.data.datasets[0].values.forEach(function(value, index, arr) {
            var textWidth = ctx.measureText("" + value).width;
            var textAngle = config.options.circumference * (value - min) / (max - min) + config.options.rotation;
            var oy = (outerRadius * panel.tickOuterRadius / 100) * Math.sin(textAngle);
            var ox = (outerRadius * panel.tickOuterRadius / 100) * Math.cos(textAngle);
            var iy = (outerRadius * panel.tickInnerRadius / 100) * Math.sin(textAngle);
            var ix = (outerRadius * panel.tickInnerRadius / 100) * Math.cos(textAngle);
            ctx.moveTo(ix, iy);
            ctx.lineTo(ox, oy);
        });
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.restore();

        ctx.save();
        ctx.translate(cx, cy);
        ctx.rotate(needleAngle);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(0, -needle.width);
        ctx.lineTo(radius, 0);
        ctx.lineTo(0, needle.width);
        ctx.fillStyle = needle.color || 'rgba(180, 0, 0, 0.8)';
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.rotate(-needleAngle);
        ctx.translate(-cx, -cy);
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = needle.circleColor || 'rgba(188, 188, 188, 1)';
        ctx.arc(cx, cy, needle.circleRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.restore();
    },

    initialize: function(chart, datasetIndex) {
        var panel = chart.chart.config.options.panel;
        var data = [100];
        var backgroundColor = [panel.scaleBackgroundColor || "rgb(120, 120, 120)"];
        var hoverBackgroundColor = [panel.scaleBackgroundColor || "rgb(120, 120, 120)"];
        var pointStyle = [panel.pointStyle];
        
        var values = [];
        for (var v = panel.min; v <= panel.max; v += panel.tickInterval) {
            values.push(v);
        }

        chart.chart.config.data.datasets[0].data = data;
        chart.chart.config.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
        chart.chart.config.data.datasets[0].hoverBackgroundColor = hoverBackgroundColor;
        chart.chart.config.data.datasets[0].pointStyle = pointStyle;
        chart.chart.config.data.datasets[0].values = values;

        Chart.controllers.doughnut.prototype.initialize.call(this, chart, datasetIndex);
    }
});

Chart.controllers.gauge = gauge;
    
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="canvas-holder">
        <canvas id="chart-speed"></canvas>
        <img id="source" src="http://example.com/image.jpg";>
    </div>


    <script>
                Chart.defaults.global.animation.duration = 0;
        Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize = 12;

        var image = document.getElementById('source');

        var configSpeed = {
            "type": "gauge",
            "data": {
                "datasets": [
                    {
                        "data": [],
                        "backgroundColor": [],
                        "borderWidth": 9,
                        "hoverBackgroundColor": [],
                        "hoverBorderWidth": 0,
                        "pointStyle": image
                    }
                ],
                "current": 135,
            },
            "options": {
                "panel": {
                    "min": 0,
                    "max": 240,
                    "tickInterval": 1,
                    "tickColor": "rgb(0, 0, 0)",
                    "tickOuterRadius": 99,
                    "tickInnerRadius": 99,
                    "scales": [],
                    "scaleColor": "rgb(0, 0, 0)",
                    "scaleBackgroundColor": "rgb(105, 125, 151)",
                    "scaleTextRadius": 80,
                    "scaleTextSize": 8,
                    "scaleTextColor": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)",
                    "scaleOuterRadius": 99,
                    "scaleInnerRadius": 99,
                },
                "needle": {
                    "lengthRadius": 100,
                    "circleColor": "rgba(188, 188, 188, 1)",
                    "color": "rgba(180, 0, 0, 0.8)",
                    "circleRadius": 7,
                    "width": 5,
                },
                "cutoutPercentage": 90,
                "rotation": (1/2+1/3)*Math.PI,
                "circumference": 2*Math.PI*2/3,
                "legend": {
                    "display": false,
                    "text": "legend"
                },
                "tooltips": {
                    "enabled": false
                },
                "title": {
                    "display": false,
                    "text": "speed",
                    "position": "bottom"
                },
                "animation": {
                    "animateRotate": true,
                    "animateScale": false
                },
                "hover": {
                    "mode": null
                }
            }
        };



        window.onload = function() {
            var ctx = document.getElementById('chart-speed').getContext('2d');
            window.speed = new Chart(ctx, configSpeed);
        };



    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is `source` in `var image = document.getElementById('source');`?

Comment: Thank you, just updated it so that it's correct now.  It still doesn't work but it should refer to this: <img id="source" src="http://example.com/image.jpg";> if I'm doing things correctly.

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48924323/how-to-add-add-chart-over-the-image

Comment: I believe so?  I've been trying to do something similar with promising results so far.  Will try to mark your answer as the answer next.

Comment: Christian, Just wanted to say thank you.  I believe your suggestion is the best approach.  It doesn't look like I can mark your answer as a question just yet FYI.  It may be that I'm too new of a user or something.

Comment: No worries, I'll flag it as a duplicate since the linked answer seems to have worked for you.